# google gadget content type URL not working

Tags: google-gadget

I have a Google Gadget with Content type=URL that suddenly stopped working. It was running in a Google Site (as the Gadget container). I can access the URL easily outside the scope of the gadget container. Did Google Sites Gadget Container change support for content type URL gadgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of browsers

- Internet Explorer - 11
- Firefox  - 25
- Google Chrome - 31

non-secure contents are not allowed. Please check your gadget URL and also for any other locations in the gadget where URLs are specified with `HTTP`. Changing those to `HTTPS` or to protocol independent would fix your issue.